# Vscode wrong React auto imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, import

I know this question has been asked hundred of times here, but I still couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I organise my React components in a folder structure where each component lives in its own folder :

[image: Example component]

The component file export the component as the default export, and the index file simply export it again :

```
export { default } from './Checkbox'
export * from './Checkbox'
```

This allows me to be able to collocate sub-components in the same folder, along with stories, helpers, and so on. Thanks to the index, I can then import my component as if it were just a single file living in my components folder :

```
import Checkbox from "components/Checkbox"
```

This has been working fine for years, but something has changed recently, not sure why, and now when I let vscode import my component automatically (using the autocomplete), here is what I end up with :

```
import Checkbox from "components/Checkbox/Checkbox"
```

It's as if vscode was ignoring my index files. Really annoying. Anyone else facing the same "issue" ? How could I fix this ?

Comment: what's the value of your `javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` and `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` setting? check both your [user settings an workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

Comment: They are both set to "shortest", for both user settings and workspace settings. I also changed "Import module specifier ending" to "minimal" just in case, but I've still got the issue

Comment: Can you please create instructions (as best you can) to reproduce the issue? (a [mre]). I'd like to try to reproduce this. I tried with two files in the directory structure you showed, but was not able. In your [mre], you will probably need to include a tsconfig.json/jsconfig.json, workspace settings.json, and maybe a package.json for the `"type"` field.